# How to display a pandas dataframe in tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I have a pandas dataframe which consists of a html table scraped from the web. I would like to display this dataframe in Tkinter. How would  be able to do this? I was thinking maybe the use of treeview, but I'm not sure how to specifically display a dataframe using treeview. If it's the case where I cannot display a pandas dataframe or it's too complicated for me because I'm very new to pandas dataframes, would it be better to store my scraped html table in a different format (instead of a dataframe) that would be easier to display in tkinter? Thanks in advance

Comment: already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348264/does-tkinter-have-a-table-widget

Comment: Thanks for this, however this does not give me the necessary answer I need. I need a simple way to display a dataframe in tkinter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a dataframe in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798950/how-to-display-a-dataframe-in-tkinter)